# Convex polygon shadows: Shortest equivalent segments

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, open-problems, plane-geometry

Let $P$ be a convex polygon.

> ***Q1***. What is the shortest collection of line segments $S$ inside $P$
> with the property that both $P$ and $S$ have the same sequence of orthogonal shadows
> as $P$ and $S$ rotate?

An *orthogonal shadow* is cast by parallel light rays.
For example, for $P$ a unit-square, the `X` below has length $2 \sqrt{2}$,
less than the perimeter $4$ of $P$, but casts the same shadows:
every lightray that intersects $\partial P$ intersects $S$;
every lightray that intersects $S$ intersects $\partial P$:

[image: Square]

> ***Q2***. Is $S$ always connected? Clearly it must span the vertices of $P$.

> ***Q3***. Is $S$ the [medial axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) of $P$?

[image: Polygon]

Medial axis. Fig.5.1(b) from [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/DCG/).

I feel I should know or be able to find the answers to these questions, but I am not hitting on
the appropriate search terms.

My real interest is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but first let's explore $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

*Answered* by Gerry Myerson:

- Q1: Open problem
- Q2: Not necessarily connected
- Q3: No

Comment: The appropriate search term is *opaque square*. See https://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/opaque/opaqsq.html for what may be the solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks, that answers all three questions!

Comment: The proposal pointed to by @GerryMyerson has a length of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3/2}$, indeed less than $2\sqrt{2}$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20Sqrt%5B1%2F2%5D%20%2B%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%20x%20%2B%202%20Sqrt%5Bx%5E2%2B%281-x%29%5E2%29%5D

Comment: For a lower bound on the length $L$ of an opaque square, I can only prove that $L \ge 2$: Consider an approximation by curves, and let $p(t)\, dt$ be the fraction of those curves whose angle with the horizontal is between $t$ and $t+dt$. Considering shadows from a light at angle $u$ with the horizontal gives the inequality $$L \int_0^{\pi}|\sin(t-u)|\, p(t)\,dt \ge |\sin u|+|\cos u|$$ and averaging those inequalities over all possible $u$ gives $L\ge2$. Can anyone get a higher lower bound?

Comment: @MattF.: Interesting question (perhaps worth posting separately?) Quite a gap between $\approx 2.64$ and your lower bound on $L$.

Answer (score 2):

The current best lower bound on the total length of segments in $S$ is 2.00002:

A. Kawamura, S. Moriyama, Y. Otachi and J. Pach, A lower bound on opaque sets,
Comput. Geom. 80 (2019), 13–22.
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comgeo.2019.01.002